# how to run moodle mobile app on android studio

Tags: android, moodle-mobile

How to run moodle mobile app on android studio? I want to add my own plugins as well.
I have followed moodle documentation https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2 but it stuck on Native build dependencies.
Code I am following: https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp

Also try to run this code on android studio ( follow:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IA3c2lpoOtU&t=757s ),I am having a blank white screen(I have paste moodle src folder on www folder and run the src/index.html)
Can somebody share video tutorial regarding this? It will be really helpful.

Comment: _"Also try to run this code on android studio"_ Maybe you missed something(?) There's no way to tell. We don't see your code and it would be awkward trying to watch the video to see what was supposed to be typed in and where. _"Can somebody share video tutorial regarding this?"_ Asking for off-site external resources is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

At first you need to add android platform to your project by these bash commands:
Removing and adding

```
npx ionic cordova platform remove android
npx ionic cordova platform remove ios
npx ionic cordova platform add android
npx ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Once you have added platforms, you can run setup using this command:

```
npm run setup
```

After successful setup you can open the the project in android studio:
android studio project location should be CORDOVA_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/platforms/android

Source:
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2